# ServerSocket constructor throws exception

Tags: java

```
package server;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;


public class TCPServer {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket serverSocket =null;
    Socket socket;
    boolean listening = true;

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Cannot listen on port: 4444.");
    }

    while (listening){
        socket = serverSocket.accept(); 
    new TCPServerThread(socket).start();
    }
    serverSocket.close();
}
```

}
this code gives this error

```
Cannot listen on port: 4444.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at server.TCPServer.main(TCPServer.java:20)
```

Comment: You are catching an exception; why don't you inspect its content?

Comment: 4444 port may be consumed by another application check for that .stop that application or disable that

Comment: 1. When you get an exception, don't just print some message of your own devising. Print the message that comes with the exception: that will tell you what's wrong. At the moment you're just asking us the meaning of your own message. We don't know any more than you do. It's your message, after all. 2. Code that depends on the success of code in a try block should be in the same try block, not after a catch block. Don't write code like this.

Comment: Are you sure that you do not open the socket the first time and you stay on blank console so you rerun your program and then the program tries to open socket on port that is already in use from your first "unnoticed" opened socket and throws exception?

Answer (score 0):

You should move the accept loop inside the try block. Because this way if the ServerSocket fails to listen your variable serverSocket will be null.

```
package server;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TCPServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket =null;
        Socket socket;
        boolean listening = true;

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
            while (listening){
                socket = serverSocket.accept(); 
                new TCPServerThread(socket).start();
            }
        serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Cannot listen on port: 4444.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Please notice how I added e.printStackTrace() to your catch block which should contain details on why the application refuses to listen on the port 4444. Most likely already a different application is listening on this port.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I don't know why it throws `NullPointerException`, but when i just debugged and inspected the exception details it was `BindException` because the port was already in use.